# By taking advantage of the fact that 1001 is divisible by $7$, form a test for divisibility by $7$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I take advantage of the fact that $1001$ is divisible by $7$, to form a test for divisibility by $7$?

My thoughts so far:

$$1001 \equiv 0  \pmod 7$$
$$1000 \equiv -1  \pmod 7$$

then I was told that I can substitute the above as follows:

$$
1000a + b \equiv 0  \pmod 7
$$

after substitution:
$$-a + b \equiv 0  \pmod 7$$

My teacher said that this is one test but it does not account for numbers that are less than or equal to $1000$. I don't really understand why I substitute into $1000a + b \equiv 0  \pmod 7$ and find this method quite confusing.

I would appreciate any clarifications on this because I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track. I found similar questions elsewhere but they had a very different approach and I'm supposed to approach it specifically through $1001$.

Comment: There is a well-known test where $a_k\dots a_1a_0$ is divisible by $7$ if and only if $(a_2a_1a_0)-(a_5a_4a_3)+(a_8a_7a_6)-\dots$ is divisible by $7$. You can try to take the given advantage and backtrack your way to this test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really a substitution.

The equation just multiplied each side by $a$ which gives us that $1000a \equiv -a \pmod 7$ and adding $b$ to each side $1000a+b \equiv -a+b \pmod 7$ is what the teacher probably meant.

And this can be generalized for numbers over $1000$.

Since $10^3 \equiv (-1) \pmod 7$ this implies that $10^{3n} \equiv (-1)^n \pmod 7$.

Thus, splitting a number every third digit from the left would work.

For example, to check if $87115$ is divisible by $7$, split it every third digit, like $\color{blue}{87}\color{red}{115}$ note that $87-115 \equiv -28 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$, thus implying that $87115$ is divisible by $7$.

To go even further, $4268635$ can be divided to $\color{red}{4} \color{green}{268} \color {purple}{635}$ and $4-268+635 \equiv 371 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$.

This is because $$4268635 \equiv 4 \times 10^6+268 \times 10^3+635 \times 1 \equiv 4(-1)^2 +268(-1)+635 \equiv 4-268+635 \equiv 371 \equiv 0 \pmod 7$$

Comment: I think I understand up to the splitting part but I am having a hard time understanding the addition/subtraction things after that.

Also, if this applies for numbers over 1000 then how do I make a general rule for all numbers?

Comment: @mangopancake See barak manos's comments for a general rule. Could you clarify on what matter of the adding and subtracting you are confused on?

Comment: I don't understand where this part: ≡4(−1)2+268(−1)+635 comes from.

Comment: @mangopancake Sorry for the late reply, it comes from the fact that $10^{3n} \equiv (-1)^n \pmod 7$. So $10^6 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$.

Comment: No worries! That makes sense now. I see how this works for numbers above 1000, but what about numbers that are below 1000 since they are only 3 digits at most?

Comment: @mangopancake You just have to use calculations on those.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of your earlier approach can also be used for numbers under 1,000, with a tweak. Note that 10a+b is congruent to 3a+b(mod 7). So is 6a+2b. Now subtract 7a, and multiply by -1. We find that if you subtract twice the ones digit from the integer you have ignoring the ones place, you get another number divisible by 7, assuming 10a+b was. This iterative procedure reduces the size of the number by a digit at each step.

Combined, you should have something that's pretty quick.